# How to use .htaccess to redirect non-www to www? (Two more questions...)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

## **Summary**

I have bought a domain (Suppose (www.)mydomain.com). And I have 3 hopes: First, when user enter mydomain.com in the address bar, it can redirect to www.mydomain.com (add www. in front of the address automatically). Second, due to the domain I bought doesn't support SSL, so when user enter https:// in front of the address, directly transform it into http://. Third, when user enter the URL that doesn't exist, show the message: “The page you were looking for doesn't exist.” and redirect to my homepage (www.mydomain.com/) after 10 seconds.

## **My try**

I have searched the Internet but just found the solution of adding www. in front of the address automatically. And below is result.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

## **Questions**

1. Is there any error in the result I found above?
2. Is there any better way to improve the result I found above?
3. How can I transform https:// into http:// when user enter https:// in front of the address?
4. When user enter the URL that doesn't exist, how to show the message: “The page you were looking for doesn't exist.” and redirect to my homepage (www.mydomain.com/) after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce both `http://` and `www.` in same rule you can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

To show a custom message for 404 (page not found) error use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<html><head><META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=/><head><body><h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist</h1></body></html>"
```

in the same `.htaccess`. This message will be displayed for 10 seconds and then browser will redirect to home page.

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Hello, you did a good job but there's still a problem: Why didn't ErrorDocument 404 page show in IE but show in any other browsers?

Comment: That is a browser problem. Not all browsers behave same and you can research on Google about your IE version. Most likely IE needs some minimum length for 404 page content.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `https` to `http` use the following rule

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

To add `www` use the following rule

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

hope this will help you in solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But if I use `http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}`, the browser will redirect to “www.www.mydomain.com”, not to “www.mydomain.com”.

Answer (score 0):

WWW redirect Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

https to http redirect use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If the user gets a 404 page not found error, you can redirect them using a page for that.
Have a page in the main directory 404.html or 404.php and keep the link for rediect there.

Comment: But if I use `http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}`, the browser will redirect to “www.www.mydomain.com”, not to “www.mydomain.com”.